# Android: Custom Tab Icon Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs

Ok, I am going to building some custom tab icon images as explained in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992639/android-how-to-build-tabs-like-the-ones-show-on-android-ui-page).  But I just need to know what size do I need to build my tab icons?  I keep on guessing and then putting them in this demo and they get squashed or changed.  What ratio in pixels do I need to create my tab icons so that they appear right?

SOLUTION:
I will give sandy the best answer, especially since he is the only answer at this point, and because I did eventually use a 9 patch image.  But I tell you what, for someone who is new to the graphic editing game, 9 patch images were a pain in the butt to use.  I eventually just download someone else 9 patch image then edited the image for what I needed.  If you look at my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992639/android-how-to-build-tabs-like-the-ones-show-on-android-ui-page).  You can see the image I use as the background behind example 1 and example 2 are 9 patch images.  And that works great because everything looks perfect when you move it to landscape mode as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a 9 - patch image.. for more see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)